# Merging a word embedding trained on a specialized topic to pre trained word embeddings

Tags: keras, word2vec

I have two word embeddings. A pretrained Glove and one that I've trained on medical related documents. The pretrained vectors contain more words, but my word vectors have better representations for medical terms. I was to fusion the two set of embeddings.

Glove (200d) has 4 million terms, and about 10% of these are also found in my own embedding (also 200d). Instead of something simple like concatenating the two (which would result in a lot of 0s), I was wondering if creating a neural network that maps a vector from the Glove space to my own embedding space would help. Specially:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=100, input_dim=200))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units=50))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units=100))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units=200))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='mse')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

The results were quite poor, and I wonder if it is because the methodology is incorrect or if the model is not tuned properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sets of word-vectors that weren't trained together have no essential relationships to each other – the distances and orientations are only interpretable within a set of vectors developed under correlated constraints. (As a simple example of this: if you were to take a set of word-vectors and negate all their coordinates, each set would be exactly equally good at finding related-words, or solving analogies, etc. But distances/directions between words in alternate sets would be nearly meaningless.)

Devising a mapping-transformation between the two is a reasonable idea, that's mentioned in one of the original Word2Vec papers ("Exploiting Similarities among Languages for Machine Translation") and the "Skip-Thought Vectors" paper, section 2.2 ("vocabulary expansion").

In those cases a linear transformation matrix is learned - not a multi-layer mapping as your code excerpt seems to suggest.

The `gensim` library for (among other things) working with word-vectors recently added a facility for learning & applying such transformations, in a [TranslationMatrix](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/0ef1ecea539045a3ffcc914a52fcb3c493146c31/gensim/models/translation_matrix.py) class. With your 10% vocabulary-overlap, it might be suitable for your purposes.